# Use Type argument as return type

Tags: c#, generics, types

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string s, Type T)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
}
```

Or in some other way, that is, using the argument T as the return type?

Comment: No, but can you show how you plan on using this?

Comment: I was just playing around and then thought of this. The example is a case of a lazy programmer who just wants to do `s.ToEnum(MoodTypes)` as a case in point.

Comment: You shouldn't need to `typeof()` a `Type` object. In fact you can obtain the type information directly from the generic argument without passing any regular arguments. For example, by calling `"Foo".ToEnum<SomeEnum>()` you can obtain `SomeEnum.Foo` without passing `typeof(SomeEnum)`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `T` both as type argument and as normal argument? Having it as type argument should be enough.

Comment: @CodeInChaos yes.. I didn't strike me when I was playing around with it. The value in <T> is inferred by VS whenever the argument is in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this string s) where T : struct
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    None,

    Special,
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = TestEnum.Special.ToString();
        var y = x.ToEnum<TestEnum>(); // y will be TestEnum.Special
    }
}
```

Comment: AH! I should have thought of that!

Comment: maybe restrict `T` to a `struct`, can't specifically do an enum, but this might be slightly better.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett You can test for `typeof(T).IsEnum()` in a static class constructor if you want to make sure nobody passes in a non-enum type.  For example, you could declare a nested static helper class to use inside the extension method.

Comment: True, although I'd still say restrict T to a struct. The more compile-time safety you can enforce the better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string s)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
string s = "Red";
Color color = s.ToEnum<Color>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, juste remove the second parameter of your method (it's totally useless) ans it will work (I tested the code) !